# What is the best way to learn CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I have some knowledge of C/C++ programming and want to learn CUDA. I'm also on a mac. So what is the best way to learn CUDA?

Comment: read some examples; then write some code

Comment: Did you visit [the site](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the [dev kit,](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/cuda_3_2_toolkit_rc.html) take one of [the examples](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/sdk/website/samples.html), and modify it.  Then write something from scatch.

you can consult these resources

[CUDA SDK Code Samples](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_get_samples.html)

[CUDA by Example: An Introduction to General-Purpose GPU Programming](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/cuda-by-example.html)

[nvidia](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_home_new.html)

Comment: I didn't look into many of the examples but when i tried to play a little bit with cuda, the following example whitepaper was "really" interesting and taught me a lot of stuff regarding cuda-performance. http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/sdk/website/C/src/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf

Comment: I tried this and really liked it https://nvidia.qwiklab.com/

Answer (score 4):

Think up a numerical problem and try to implement it. Make sure that you have an NVIDIA card first. :) Download the SDK from NVIDIA web site. Read the "CUDA programming guide", it's less than 200 pages long and sufficiently well written that you should be able to do it in one pass. Pick a sufficiently simple sample and start modifying/rewriting it.